# Application class: getDefaultHostName() NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

When starting the application, I was trying to create preferences and edit its values, getDefaultHostName() method threw a Null Pointer Exception. Below, there is a code sample, if anyone can help. Thanks..

```
private val sContext: MyApp? = null
```

```
private fun isEmulator(): Boolean {
        return ((Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("sdk_gphone_x86")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")) || Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith(
            "generic"
        ) || "google_sdk" == Build.PRODUCT || Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("vbox"))
    }
```

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super<Application>.onCreate()
        /*Vid*/
        instance = this
        try {
            val pi = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
            instance.sAppVersion = pi.versionName
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(instance.sAppVersion)) {
                instance.sAppVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
            }
            instance.sAppBuild = pi.versionCode
            if (instance.sAppBuild <= 0) {
                instance.sAppBuild = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.w(MyApp.TAG, "Failed to retrieve app version", e)
        }
        // Check if preferences already exist. If not, create them.
        val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pref.getString(Utils.PREFS_HOST_NAME, null))) {
            // No preferences found. Save default values.
            val editor = pref.edit()
            editor.putString(Utils.PREFS_HOST_NAME, getDefaultHostName())
            editor.putBoolean(Utils.PREFS_USE_TLS, getDefaultTLS())
            editor.apply()
        }
    }
```

```
fun getDefaultHostName(): String {
        return sContext!!.resources
            .getString(if (isEmulator()) R.string.emulator_host_name else R.string.default_host_name)
    }
```